# Make two variables reactive both ways

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I want to make two variables reactive both ways. That means, if i change, lets say variable `a`, then i want variable `b` to change specified by some defined function, and if i change variable `b`, then i want `a` to change by the same function, but inversly:

```
$: b = 2 * a
$: a = 1/2 * b // This lines makes these dependencies cyclical.
```

I have this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/5c4b817280bd4cd894e626f991c04c99?version=3.59.1) to show what i want. How can i achieve this? (Ideally by smart svelte assignments, as the $-sign, but "on:input" solutions will also work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can actually simplify without using `$:` for this case, How about?

```
<script>
    let a = 1;
</script>

<input type="number" bind:value={a} > <br>

<input type="number" value={2 * a} on:change={(e) => a = 1/2 * e.target.value}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved one assignment into a function (reactive statements don't analyze the functions they call) and got the results you want: [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/322a436d56f743eba924c884ae62ca02?version=3.59.1)

One caveat: As you can see from watching the console, though changing `b` runs only `a`'s assignment as we'd like, changing `a` runs both assignments. I tried a few things but couldn't get both variables causing only the other's assignment using only reactive (`$:`) statements, though it should be doable with an `on:input` solution.

(Incidentally, I'm the author of a [two-way derived store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-writable-derived) that guarantees only one callback is called when either end changes, but that may be excessive for your needs.)